# Phone gap File type from DATA_URL

Tags: cordova, camera, base64

How can i get the file properties like size, type from DATA_URL. I am using the following code.

```
 function getImage() {
     // Retrieve image file location from specified source
     navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, null, {
         quality: 50,
         destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
         saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
         sourceType: 2
     });
 }

 function uploadPhoto(data) {
     // Here i want to get file type/ size
 }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do this directly, because the picture is returned as Base64 string. However, it is possible to get the type and size.

**Type**:   You can define the type yourself when setting the options for making a picture with the cordova plugin. This options is set with the `encodingType`. This can be set to:

```
Camera.EncodingType = {
JPEG : 0,               // Return JPEG encoded image
PNG : 1                 // Return PNG encoded image };
```

**Size**: can be calculated with a simple method like this:

```
        var imageByteCount = function (imageString) {
        return encodeURI(imageString)
              .split(/%(?:u[0-9A-F]{2})?[0-9A-F]{2}|./).length -1;
    }
```

However, it is impossible to get other information of the image. You can return the image as `FILE_URI` or `NATIVE_URI` and load the file with the File API of Cordova. You can probably get more information about the file itself this way.